# including static library to ./configure

Tags: makefile, configure

how do i include two static library while executing the command `./configure`. Ex:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr \
    LDFLAGS="-L/home/lancy/dictionary/src/WordNet-3.0/lib -lWN"
```

here only one static library is include. how do i add such another static library to `LDFLAGS` in the same command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add more linker switches, e.g.

```
LDFLAGS="-L/path/1/ -lLib1 -L/path/2/ -lLib2"
```

But you might do better editing these into the Makefile.in unless you need them for the configure checks too?